# Align items horizontaly with display flex

Tags: css

I want to align the item with class `test` a the end of the page, at the right, and the first 3 list items to set at the start of the page (left side). How to do this with display flex?

```css
ul{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  list-style-type: none;

}

li {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.test {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class='test'>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```css
ul{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.test {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class='test'>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

just assign margin left auto to test element.

```css
ul{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.test{
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class='test'>test</li>
</ul>
```